# Local tensorflow running with GPU out of memory

Tags: python, gpu, tensorflow

I'm trying to get into the Deep Learning world using Tensorflow but after getting to run it with my GPU I encounter an error while running a basic [object detector app](https://github.com/datitran/object_detector_app).

The error is a **CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY** saying that it cannot allocate 3.9GB of memory when I actually have 16GB. Actually the error is solved when I try using only 1 worker, but I believe it is not using the total memory.

Sorry for my ignorance, but when you run Tensorflow with GPU does it use the RAM memory or a GPU memory? Should I run it with CPU? In AWS maybe?
 What do you recommend?

Again, I don't even know if this question even makes much sense, so really, thank you in advance!

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 64bit.
Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-6500U CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4
Graphics card: GeForce 940MX/PCIe/SSE2

**Logs:**

```
2017-09-16 11:39:56.458856: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-09-16 11:39:56.458878: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-09-16 11:39:56.458887: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-09-16 11:39:56.458894: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-09-16 11:39:56.458900: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-09-16 11:39:56.589540: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:893] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2017-09-16 11:39:56.590428: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:955] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce 940MX
major: 5 minor: 0 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.2415
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 3.95GiB
Free memory: 143.25MiB
2017-09-16 11:39:56.590540: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:976] DMA: 0 
2017-09-16 11:39:56.590546: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:986] 0:   Y 
2017-09-16 11:39:56.590554: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1045] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce 940MX, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
2017-09-16 11:39:56.595486: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:924] failed to allocate 143.25M (150208512 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
```

**Graphics card:**

```
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940MX] (rev a2)
DeviceName: NVIDIA N16S-GTR
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company GM108M [GeForce 940MX]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
Memory at a3000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
I/O ports at 5000 [size=128]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_381, nvidia_381_drm
```

**RAM:**

```
Handle 0x0019, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0018
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8192 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: Bottom-Slot 1(left) 
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 2133 MHz
    Manufacturer: Samsung
    Serial Number: 21152224
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: M471A1G43DB0-CPB    
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 2133 MHz
    Minimum Voltage: 1.5 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.5 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V

Handle 0x001A, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0018
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8192 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: Bottom-Slot 2(right)
    Bank Locator: BANK 2
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 2133 MHz
    Manufacturer: Samsung
    Serial Number: 21152224
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: M471A1G43DB0-CPB    
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 2133 MHz
    Minimum Voltage: 1.5 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.5 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
```

Comment: Just being curious: How did you now solved your problem?

Comment: Hey Patwie, thank you so much for the answer! I didn't have the time yet to check it but as soon as I can I will try it out and let you know.
Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Your GPU only comes along with 3.9 GB according to the TensorFlow output. But the memory available for the TF-Session is just `143.25MiB`. 
So you either have another TF-Session running which uses the GPU or another GPU-enabled process occupying the GPU. I suspect the first one, as TF usually takes all GPU memory.

Second question:
TensorFlow used the so-called pinned memory to improve transfer speed. So you need both RAM and GPU memory. Think of TF can only use min(RAM, GPUmem) as a rule of thumb.

I suggest to do the following:
- run `nvidia-smi` in another terminal to see if there is another process on that GPU and use the memory.
- run `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES= python ....` to start you app in the CPU mode (if the code supports it)

The output should be like

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI xxx.xx                 Driver Version: xxx.xx                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  TITAN Xp            Off  | 0000:02:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 23%   34C    P8     9W / 250W |      0MiB / 12189MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    2     28289    C   python                                        6023MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and `ps aux | grep 28289` tells you more about the process running on that GPU.

**edit**: Each worker seems to use a [single session](https://github.com/datitran/object_detector_app/blob/master/object_detection_multithreading.py#L71) this is usually a bad idea on a single GPU and explains why there is no more memory.The first worker takes all memory on the GPU.

But this gives a 3rd possible solution: Hack in the following lines:

```
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=1 / num_workers)
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))
```